# Relationship between core and threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool

Would someone please explain to me what is the point to create a multithreading application if I only have below configuration:

```
2 core, 8GB
```

So I observe that tomcat will spin up 10 HTTP threads by default. And if I also create a thread pool and set the size to 10 which add up the total to spin up 20 threads.

Now since I only have 2 core, how is possible my application will have a good performance? How can 2 core handle 20 threads?

Comment: I guess knowing how computers work isn't so common even in the programming community these days.

Comment: It's possible in the same way you are able to tweet while waiting for your bread to be toasted, or to be in three chat rooms at the same time, answering in one while waiting for an answer in the two others.